# How to place the Docker container directory in a auto-mounted partition?

Tags: mount, docker

I don't have a lot of space on my root directory, so I'm trying to set up the default location for Docker containers in a different hard drive, one that is automatically mounted on `/media/znorg/MyDisk/` on startup.

I edited `/etc/docker/daemon.json` so now it looks like this:

```
{
  "data-root":"/media/znorg/MyDisk/docker/"
}
```

The problem is that the docker daemon seems to be trying to find this directory before it is correctly mounted on startup, resulting in the creation of a brand new `/media/znorg/MyDisk/docker/` directory with default files.

Then the secondary hard drive is being mounted at `/media/znorg/MyDisk-1/` instead.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: One possible workaround is to disable Docker autostart and manually run it when You need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount the drive using the configuration file `/etc/fstab`. Then it will be mounted while the system is booting, and available when the docker daemon starts. External drives automatically mounted under `/media` are mounted only when the graphical desktop is ready.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work, I still have the same problem

Comment: Still, correctly announcing this in fstab is how this works in Linux. A drive mounted in fstab will not be automatically mounted again elsewhere.

Comment: I looked into it again, and there was a problem in the fstab configuration. It works now, thanks!